# BizTalk: Deploying large XML schema (OAGIS) split into multiple documents

Tags: xsd, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-deployment

Currently, I am deploying the [OAGIS XML schema](http://www.oagi.org/oagis/OAGi-BPI-Platform/org_openapplications_oagis/9_5-RC-1) set to BizTalk 2010 with Visual Studio 2010. It has taken some 3 hours this far with no finish in sight. In the Visual Studio output log, there are some 18,000 lines now. I keep getting messages such as:

```
warning DEPLOY: Schema "OagiSchemata.OAGi_BPI_Platform.org_openapplications_platform._1_2_1.Common.OAGi.Components.Fields, 
OagiSchemata, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=afe0ae2252ec000f" and a previously deployed schema "" 
have the same target namespace "http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9". Target namespaces should be unique.
```

Indeed, there are several schema documents with the same namespace but it should be no issue. The XML schema specification allows a schema designer to split a schema into multiple files. In Altova XMLSpy, the same schema set works out perfectly with neither errors nor warnings.

Can BizTalk even handle a large schema split into multiple files? If it can, is there any way to speed up deployment? This is simply insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deployment finished finally with a total duration of 6 hours. In the log, there were about 25,000 warnings in total, all of them similar to the one in the question.

*Can BizTalk even handle a large schema split into multiple files?*

Despite warnings, the XML schema set seems to work without problems.

*Is there any way to speed up deployment?*

An obvious way is to remove any parts that are not required for the current usage. Actually, the current deployment only includes the *PurchaseOrder* noun (there are dozens of nouns in total). The actual problem seems to be the number of reusable components in OAGIS. They are located in a few files, but they are many. Removing any unused components would require editing the original schema files, which is not very practical.

Comment: Did you find a way to speed things up...? I experience the same problem. I am thinking about suppressing warning message, but I can't find out the warning number...

Comment: @JERKER : we finally gave up using BizTalk as it did not support our business very well anyway. Its limitations in XML schema support is only one example of its shortcomings and old-fashioned architecture.